# PostgreSQL How to change offset of a timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

We can see timezone offsets using `SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names`; I want to know how we can change this only for a specific timezone

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the timezone data, you must update the tzdata files. You cannot change the time zone definitions from within the database engine.

Usually you would just update to the last PostgreSQL point release with the current tzdata.